# how do you type instance variable caching in Sorbet?

Tags: sorbet

I have code that looks like this ([playground link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20compute_expensive%0A%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20expensive%0A%20%20%20%20%40expensive%20%7C%7C%3D%20T.let(compute_expensive%2C%20T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%0A%20%20end%0Aend)):

```rb
# typed: strict
class A
  extend T::Sig

  sig { returns(T::Array[Integer]) }
  def compute_expensive
    [1, 2, 3]
  end
  
  sig { returns(T::Array[Integer]) }
  def expensive
    @expensive ||= T.let(compute_expensive, T::Array[Integer])
  end
end
```

This fails to typecheck, saying that:

```
editor.rb:12: The instance variable @expensive must be declared inside initialize or declared nilable https://srb.help/5005
    12 |    @expensive ||= T.let(compute_expensive, Integer)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried a couple things to get around this…

- When I declare the type as `T.nilable(Integer)`, Sorbet says that the return type does not match the sig. Fair.
- When I declare the type in `initialize` as `@expensive = nil`, Sorbet says that `nil` does not type check with the `Integer` definition below. Also fair.
- If I declare `@expensive = []` in `initialize`, my assignment with `||=` becomes unreachable.
- I can of course say `@expensive = compute_expensive if @expensive.empty?` and then return `@expensive` but I'm more interested in how Sorbet's type system can accommodate the `||=` pattern.

This feels like a really common pattern in Ruby to me! How can I get Sorbet to type-check it for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693361/how-would-you-do-rose-memoization-with-sorbet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you do rose memoization with Sorbet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693361/how-would-you-do-rose-memoization-with-sorbet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Playground Link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20void%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize%0A%20%20%20%20%40expensive%20%3D%20T.let(nil%2C%20T.nilable(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D))%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20compute_expensive%0A%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20expensive%0A%20%20%20%20%40expensive%20%7C%7C%3D%20compute_expensive%0A%20%20end%0Aend) right back to you.

So, really using the initialize is the important part here.

```rb
  sig { void }
  def initialize
    @expensive = T.let(nil, T.nilable(T::Array[Integer]))
  end
```

Because the memoization is still nil up until the point it's actually called, you have to allow for it to be nil, along with `T::Array[Integer]`, which then neccessitates for you to add it to the initialization to make the class sound.

Comment: FWIW, you don't necessarily need the `initialize`, you can do it inline too

[Playground Link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20compute_expensive%0A%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D)%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20expensive%0A%20%20%20%20%40expensive%20%7C%7C%3D%20T.let(nil%2C%20T.nilable(T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D))%0A%20%20%20%20%40expensive%20%7C%7C%3D%20compute_expensive%0A%20%20end%0Aend)